# How to put a p5.js recorder on pause

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I am using p5.js library sound.

The sketch asks the user a question, then records the answer and then asks the next question.

In the end, the sketch is to save the file with just the user’s answers Currently if I stop the recorder it sends the result to the sound file which is later saved.

I can turn the mic on and off. This solves the problem partially. Only the input is recorded, however, as the Recorder object does not pause there are lengthy empty pauses in the resulting file.

If I stop the recorder the result is immediately sent to the sound file.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sure https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/520236